# Create a live video stream using images

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am looking for a way to generate a live video stream from a single image that is updated constantly. The live stream would display the last generated image repeatedly until a new image arrives.

Something like:

`tool -input source.png -output video.mp4 -live -daemon`

where `source.png` would be overwritten constantly by a 3rd party tool. The same inode can be used (edited based on Kamil's comment).

I could then open `video.mp4` on a media player and "watch" the last `source.png` being updated live. The stream could be forgotten if nobody is watching it so there is no need to save every video frame to the filesystem.

I'm not sure what tool(s) if available to use for that.

Comment: (1) "where `source.png` would be overwritten constantly by a 3rd party tool" – Would it be overwritten in place (same inode)? or atomically replaced by renaming another file (different inode) when it's ready? (2) Do you want a stream that gets forgotten when nobody listens? or a regular file `video.mp4` that can clog the filesystem eventually? // Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've provided the edits.